# How do I make an event calendar?

Tags: views, datetime

Im on D7. I have been pulling  my hair out trying to get this working.

Im using these modules:

- [Calendar](https://drupal.org/project/calendar) (7.x-3.4)
- [Date](https://drupal.org/project/date) (7.x-2.6)
- [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) (7.x-3.5)

I have tried to use the calendar dev version but I get the same problem.

When ever I try and create a calendar view, all I see is a blank calendar. Meaning nothing shows up in the calendar cells even though I have fields assigned. I am "Adding a view from template" and selecting the template that has my date field (I have also tried the one that uses the content creation date, but no luck). Has anyone else had this problem? Why would it not be working? I can make a view of a simple list of nodes that have the date field, so why not a calendar view?

Here is my view:

```
    $view = new view();
$view->name = 'calendar';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'Calendar';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Calendar';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['link_display'] = 'page_1';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['query_comment'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'date_views_pager';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['date_id'] = 'month';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'calendar_style';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['name_size'] = '3';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['with_weekno'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['multiday_theme'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['theme_style'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['max_items'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'calendar_entity';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['hide_alter_empty'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['id'] = 'field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['table'] = 'field_data_field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['field'] = 'field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['hide_alter_empty'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['settings'] = array(
  'format_type' => 'short',
  'fromto' => 'both',
  'multiple_number' => '',
  'multiple_from' => '',
  'multiple_to' => '',
  'show_repeat_rule' => '',
);
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['group_rows'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['delta_offset'] = '0';
/* Sort criterion: Content: Date (field_date) */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_date_value']['id'] = 'field_date_value';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_date_value']['table'] = 'field_data_field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_date_value']['field'] = 'field_date_value';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;

/* Display: Month */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Month', 'page_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['hide_admin_links'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'date_views_pager';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['date_id'] = 'month';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['link_format'] = 'clean';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'calendar_style';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['name_size'] = '3';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['mini'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['with_weekno'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['multiday_theme'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['theme_style'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['max_items'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'calendar_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['colors']['legend'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['arguments'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['id'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['field'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['add_delta'] = 'yes';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['date_fields'] = array(
  'field_data_field_date.field_date_value' => 'field_data_field_date.field_date_value',
);
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'calendar-node-field-date/month';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'default tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Month';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['tab_options']['type'] = 'normal';
$handler->display->display_options['tab_options']['title'] = 'Calendar';
$handler->display->display_options['tab_options']['weight'] = '0';

/* Display: Week */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Week', 'page_2');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['hide_admin_links'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'date_views_pager';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['date_id'] = 'week';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['link_format'] = 'clean';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'calendar_style';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['calendar_type'] = 'week';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['name_size'] = '3';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['mini'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['with_weekno'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['multiday_theme'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['theme_style'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['max_items'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'calendar_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['arguments'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['id'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['field'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['granularity'] = 'week';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['add_delta'] = 'yes';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['date_fields'] = array(
  'field_data_field_date.field_date_value' => 'field_data_field_date.field_date_value',
);
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'calendar-node-field-date/week';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Week';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '2';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;

/* Display: Day */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Day', 'page_3');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['hide_admin_links'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'date_views_pager';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['date_id'] = 'day';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['link_format'] = 'clean';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'calendar_style';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['calendar_type'] = 'day';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['name_size'] = '3';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['mini'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['with_weekno'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['multiday_theme'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['theme_style'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['max_items'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'calendar_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['arguments'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['id'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['field'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['granularity'] = 'day';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['date_fields'] = array(
  'field_data_field_date.field_date_value' => 'field_data_field_date.field_date_value',
);
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'calendar-node-field-date/day';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Day';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '3';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;

/* Display: Year */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Year', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['hide_admin_links'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'date_views_pager';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['date_id'] = 'year';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['link_format'] = 'clean';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'calendar_style';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['calendar_type'] = 'year';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['name_size'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['mini'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['with_weekno'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['multiday_theme'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['theme_style'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['max_items'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'calendar_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['hide_alter_empty'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['id'] = 'field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['table'] = 'field_data_field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['field'] = 'field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['hide_alter_empty'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['settings'] = array(
  'format_type' => 'short',
  'fromto' => 'both',
  'multiple_number' => '',
  'multiple_from' => '',
  'multiple_to' => '',
  'show_repeat_rule' => '',
);
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['group_rows'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['delta_offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['arguments'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['id'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['field'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['granularity'] = 'year';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['add_delta'] = 'yes';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['date_fields'] = array(
  'field_data_field_date.field_date_value' => 'field_data_field_date.field_date_value',
);
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'calendar-node-field-date/year';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Year';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '4';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['use_ajax'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_ajax'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['hide_admin_links'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'date_views_pager';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['date_id'] = 'mini';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'calendar_style';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['name_size'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['mini'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['with_weekno'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['multiday_theme'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['theme_style'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['max_items'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'calendar_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['arguments'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['id'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['field'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['add_delta'] = 'yes';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['date_fields'] = array(
  'field_data_field_date.field_date_value' => 'field_data_field_date.field_date_value',
);

/* Display: Upcoming */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Upcoming', 'block_2');
$handler->display->display_options['display_description'] = 'Upcoming events block';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['hide_admin_links'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['use_more'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_more'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '5';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'list';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filter_groups'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filters'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['id'] = 'date_filter';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['field'] = 'date_filter';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['operator'] = '>=';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['default_date'] = 'now';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['add_delta'] = 'yes';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['date_fields'] = array(
  'field_data_field_date.field_date_value' => 'field_data_field_date.field_date_value',
);
```

And here are some pictures of my view:

[image]
[image]
[image]

And the contextual filter settings:

[image]
[image]

Comment: could you take a screen shot of the view configuration page and send it.

Comment: sure, ill add it above

Comment: what is the settings of the contextual filter?

Comment: Ill add them above :)

Comment: the view looks fine to me. are you sure there are contents with dates with in the month you are viewing  and they are published?

Comment: yep, and I'm able to make a simple list of them. It only wont show in calendar view.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7253/discussion-between-mohammed-shameem-and-oobie11)

Answer (score 1):

I have an Event Calendar on my website,

Import this view and see if it works for you.

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'calendar_3';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'Calendar';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Calendar Event';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['link_display'] = 'page_1';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['query_comment'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'date_views_pager';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['date_id'] = 'month';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'calendar_style';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['name_size'] = '3';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['with_weekno'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['multiday_theme'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['theme_style'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['max_items'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'calendar_entity';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['hide_alter_empty'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Re-Enter Event Date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_event_date']['id'] = 'field_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_event_date']['table'] = 'field_data_field_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_event_date']['field'] = 'field_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_event_date']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_event_date']['settings'] = array(
  'format_type' => 'long',
  'fromto' => 'both',
  'multiple_number' => '',
  'multiple_from' => '',
  'multiple_to' => '',
);
/* Field: Content: Body */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body']['id'] = 'body';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body']['table'] = 'field_data_body';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body']['field'] = 'body';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Content: Rendered Node */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['id'] = 'rendered_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['table'] = 'views_entity_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['field'] = 'rendered_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['link_to_entity'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['view_mode'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['bypass_access'] = 0;
/* Field: Colorbox: Colorbox trigger */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['colorbox']['id'] = 'colorbox';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['colorbox']['table'] = 'colorbox';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['colorbox']['field'] = 'colorbox';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['colorbox']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['colorbox']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['colorbox']['trigger_field'] = 'rendered_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['colorbox']['popup'] = '<html>
<body>
<h1>[title]</h1>
<br>
<b>Description: </b> <br>[body]
<br>

<b>Date: </b>[field_event_date]
<br><br>
<b>Note: </b> For more info, Click on the title.
</body>
</html>';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['colorbox']['gid'] = 1;
/* Sort criterion: Content: Re-Enter Event Date -  start date (field_event_date) */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_event_date_value']['id'] = 'field_event_date_value';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_event_date_value']['table'] = 'field_data_field_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_event_date_value']['field'] = 'field_event_date_value';
/* Contextual filter: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['id'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['field'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['date_fields'] = array(
  'field_data_field_event_date.field_event_date_value' => 'field_data_field_event_date.field_event_date_value',
);

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['use_ajax'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_ajax'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'date_views_pager';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['date_id'] = 'mini';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'calendar_style';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['name_size'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['mini'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['with_weekno'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['multiday_theme'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['theme_style'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['max_items'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'calendar_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['arguments'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['id'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['field'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['add_delta'] = 'yes';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['date_fields'] = array(
  'field_data_field_event_date.field_event_date_value' => 'field_data_field_event_date.field_event_date_value',
);

/* Display: Upcoming */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Upcoming', 'block_2');
$handler->display->display_options['display_description'] = 'Upcoming events block';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['use_more'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_more'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '5';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'list';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filter_groups'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filters'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['id'] = 'date_filter';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['field'] = 'date_filter';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['operator'] = '>=';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['default_date'] = 'now';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['add_delta'] = 'yes';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['date_fields'] = array(
  'field_data_field_event_date.field_event_date_value' => 'field_data_field_event_date.field_event_date_value',
);

/* Display: Year */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Year', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'date_views_pager';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['date_id'] = 'year';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['link_format'] = 'clean';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'calendar_style';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['calendar_type'] = 'year';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['name_size'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['mini'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['with_weekno'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['multiday_theme'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['theme_style'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['max_items'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'calendar_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['hide_alter_empty'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Re-Enter Event Date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_event_date']['id'] = 'field_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_event_date']['table'] = 'field_data_field_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_event_date']['field'] = 'field_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_event_date']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_event_date']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_event_date']['hide_alter_empty'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_event_date']['settings'] = array(
  'format_type' => 'short',
  'fromto' => 'both',
  'multiple_number' => '',
  'multiple_from' => '',
  'multiple_to' => '',
  'show_repeat_rule' => '',
);
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_event_date']['group_rows'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_event_date']['delta_offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['arguments'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['id'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['field'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['granularity'] = 'year';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['add_delta'] = 'yes';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['date_fields'] = array(
  'field_data_field_event_date.field_event_date_value' => 'field_data_field_event_date.field_event_date_value',
);
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'calendar-node-field-event-date/year';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Year';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '4';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;

/* Display: Day */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Day', 'page_3');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'date_views_pager';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['date_id'] = 'day';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['link_format'] = 'clean';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'calendar_style';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['calendar_type'] = 'day';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['name_size'] = '3';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['mini'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['with_weekno'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['multiday_theme'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['theme_style'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['max_items'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'calendar_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['arguments'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['id'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['field'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['granularity'] = 'day';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['date_fields'] = array(
  'field_data_field_event_date.field_event_date_value' => 'field_data_field_event_date.field_event_date_value',
);
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'calendar-node-field-event-date/day';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Day';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '3';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;

/* Display: Month */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Month', 'page_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'date_views_pager';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['date_id'] = 'month';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['link_format'] = 'clean';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'calendar_style';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['name_size'] = '3';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['mini'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['with_weekno'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['multiday_theme'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['theme_style'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['max_items'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'calendar_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['colors']['legend'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['colors']['calendar_colors_type'] = array(
  'university_courses' => '#ffffff',
  'event_calendar' => '#ffffff',
  'event' => '#ffffff',
  'online_training' => '#ffffff',
  'new_event' => '#ffffff',
  'page' => '#ffffff',
  'panel' => '#ffffff',
  'requirements' => '#ffffff',
  'training_resources' => '#ffffff',
  'story' => '#ffffff',
  'webform' => '#ffffff',
  'webinar' => '#ffffff',
);
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['arguments'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['id'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['field'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['add_delta'] = 'yes';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['date_fields'] = array(
  'field_data_field_event_date.field_event_date_value' => 'field_data_field_event_date.field_event_date_value',
);
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'calendar_event';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'default tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Month';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['tab_options']['type'] = 'normal';
$handler->display->display_options['tab_options']['title'] = 'Calendar';
$handler->display->display_options['tab_options']['weight'] = '0';

/* Display: Week */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Week', 'page_2');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'date_views_pager';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['date_id'] = 'week';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['link_format'] = 'clean';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'calendar_style';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['calendar_type'] = 'week';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['name_size'] = '3';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['mini'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['with_weekno'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['multiday_theme'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['theme_style'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['max_items'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'calendar_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['arguments'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['id'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['field'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['granularity'] = 'week';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['add_delta'] = 'yes';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['date_fields'] = array(
  'field_data_field_event_date.field_event_date_value' => 'field_data_field_event_date.field_event_date_value',
);
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'calendar-node-field-event-date/week';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Week';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '2';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your view isn't working, but there are a number of tutorials on building an event calendar in D7.

- Acquia webinar on building an event calendar ([YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQSR7pNP3L8)) ([presentation slides](http://www.slideshare.net/AcquiaInc/build-an-event-calendar-in-drupal))
- [Events calendar feature](http://drupal.org/project/events_calendar_feature) on drupal.org-- you could install this on a test site and see how they have everything structured
- [CiviCRM Events Calendar](http://drupal.org/project/civicrm_events), a module for the popular CiviCRM distribution-- again, you could install this and see how it's set up
- And here's a video on [setting up Calendar 3.x](http://vimeo.com/26853285)

Comment: Thanks, I've done all that, but It still wont work.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the Calendar module is really bad and basically abandoned (although widely adopted.) This [native civicrm extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/event-calendar-extension) is another approach.

Also using [jquery fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).